# Make javascript typing carousel loop once

Tags: javascript, css, text

I've adapted this code I found to do what I want almost perfectly, except it continues to loop.  I'd like it to just type "zero", delete, type "one" and then stop.  I've tried amending a few things in here, but can't get it to work.

```
    <span
     class="txt-rotate"
     style="font-size: 72px; font-weight: 500; line-height: 72px; margin-bottom: 20px; color: white;"
     data-period="2000"
     data-rotate='[ "zero.", "one." ]'></span>

<script>
var TxtRotate = function(el, toRotate, period) {
  this.toRotate = toRotate;
  this.el = el;
  this.loopNum = 0;
  this.period = parseInt(period, 10) || 2000;
  this.txt = '';
  this.tick();
  this.isDeleting = false;
};

TxtRotate.prototype.tick = function() {
  var i = this.loopNum % this.toRotate.length;
  var fullTxt = this.toRotate[i];

  if (this.isDeleting) {
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length - 1);
  } else {
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length + 1);
  }

  this.el.innerHTML = '<span class="wrap">'+this.txt+'</span>';

  var that = this;
  var delta = 300 - Math.random() * 100;

  if (this.isDeleting) { delta /= 2; }

  if (!this.isDeleting && this.txt === fullTxt) {
    delta = this.period;
    this.isDeleting = true;
  } else if (this.isDeleting && this.txt === '') {
    this.isDeleting = false;
   this.loopNum++;
    delta = 500;
  }

  setTimeout(function() {
    that.tick();
  }, delta);
};

window.onload = function() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('txt-rotate');
  for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
    var toRotate = elements[i].getAttribute('data-rotate');
    var period = elements[i].getAttribute('data-period');
    if (toRotate) {
      new TxtRotate(elements[i], JSON.parse(toRotate), period);
    }
  }
  // INJECT CSS
  var css = document.createElement("style");
  css.type = "text/css";
  css.innerHTML = ".txt-rotate > .wrap { border-right: 0.08em solid #fff }";
  document.body.appendChild(css);
};
</script>
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Use that:

```
TxtRotate.prototype.tick = function() {
  //Don't use modulo, it causes the loop. If there is no full text, you are out of the loop and you don't want to do anything.
  var fullTxt = this.toRotate[this.loopNum];
  if(fullTxt) {
    if (this.isDeleting) {
      this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length - 1);
    } else {
      this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length + 1);
    }

    this.el.innerHTML = '<span class="wrap">'+this.txt+'</span>';

    var that = this;
    var delta = 300 - Math.random() * 100;

    if (this.isDeleting) { delta /= 2; }

    if (!this.isDeleting && this.txt === fullTxt) {
      // If you are on the last item of the toRotate array, break the loop before deletion.
      if(this.loopNum >= this.toRotate.length-1) {
        return;
      }
      delta = this.period;
      this.isDeleting = true;
    } else if (this.isDeleting && this.txt === '') {
      this.isDeleting = false;
      this.loopNum++;
      delta = 500;
    }

    setTimeout(function() {
      that.tick();
    }, delta);
  }
};
```

Hoping this helps ;)

Comment: Super quick, thank you!  One thing though ... it deletes the final "one".  I'd like this to remain on the page when it's finished doing it's thing ... how would I achieve that?  Thanks again!

Comment: I would have to prevent the deletion to happen on the last data to rotate. I'm gonna check it, i'll edit my answer and publish another comment to keep you in touch.

Comment: It should be ok by now ;) though, please note that I worked from your piece of code, but i think there should be cleaner ways to get to your expected result!

Comment: @sjahan is there a way to speed up the typing speed? Like with this code, it is really slow. I wanted to know if u can speed it up a bit